# Can not find Module fs-plus

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, babeljs

Previously I was using `Meteor 1.2`, `npm: '2.11.3'` and `node: '0.12.7'` in my application
and I was using

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
const remote = require('remote');
var fsPlus =remote.require('fs-plus');
var nconf = remote.require('nconf');
```

**Currently I migrate it in `Meteor 1.4` , `npm: '2.15.9'` and  `node: '4.5.0'`**
for above code `Error`: `path module not found` not found so I did some changes
and Changes are

```
function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; }
var path = _interopRequireDefault('path');
var fs = _interopRequireDefault('fs');
const remote = _interopRequireDefault('remote');
// It is working but
// same is not working for 
var fsPlus =remote.require('fs-plus');
var nconf = remote.require('nconf');
```

`It is showing Error o.require is not found` and file line denoting to fs-plus

Can you Please help me out ?

`Dependencies`

I am using like this

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "0.1.47",
  "main": "main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "1.3.7",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.2.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-electron": "^5.0.0",
    "grunt-electron-installer": "^2.1.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.4",
    "time-grunt": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "edge-atom-shell": "^5.0.1",
    "finalhandler": "^0.5.0",
    "fs-extra": "^0.30.0",
    "fs-plus": "^2.9.2",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.3",
    "nconf": "^0.8.4",
    "py-logging": "^0.8.1",
    "remote": "^0.2.6",
    "serve-static": "^1.11.1",
    "server-destroy": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add error message?

Comment: It is already added

Comment: The problem seems to be not with `fs-plus` but `remote`. Does your app know what this is?

Comment: previously It was working in `Node '0.12.7'` but not in `node: '4.5.0'`

Comment: have you tried to reinstall all packages after meteor version updation?

Comment: Yes I tried it.

Comment: @durrrr: problem was with require but resolved it by
 function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { 'default': obj }; } and now `remote.require is not working`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how is this set up for you, but in your **package.js** should be this kind of block to let the package know about npm dependencies:

```
Npm.depends({
    'fs-plus': '2.9.2'
});
```

and then you may just `Npm.require` it.

Assuming you're not working on a package and have installed the fs-plus package to your app by `npm install --save fs-plus`, `import` it where you need it. You can read about using npm packages in an Meteor application [here](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html).

Comment: I added above how I am using the same

Comment: Are you sure you're doing `Npm.require('fs-plus')` and not `remote.require`? I honestly don't know what that is...

Comment: I am doing remote.require